# How do I add an exception to CodeIgniter's XSS filtering?

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, exception, xss

I have a **textbox**, which can basically **add background color to text**. Here is an example of the end-result output of that textbox:

```
<p><span style="background-color: rgb(196, 189, 151);">Text</span></p>
```

When I apply CodeIgniter's XSS Filtering to the above code, the filtering modifies it and unfortunately, turns it into this:

```
<p><span  rgb(196, 189, 151);">Text</span></p>
```

I don't want this to happen; however, I also do not want to completely disable XSS filtering for the textbox. Is there a way to make an **exception** to that kind of formatted HTML in CodeIgniter's XSS module?

Comment: I would suggest that you use HTML Purifier for these fields (where you want html but you don't want javascripts, it would give you the same protection without affecting the html

Comment: Yes, that is possible, but it would still be interesting to know how to do this in CI. :)

Comment: It doesn't take exceptions, it only takes a string & TRUE/FALSE to make additional checks for images.

Comment: You could extend the form validation class and override the xss_clean function there. but where and how do u apply this filter?

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking...